# Polygons Overlap When Drawing on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have two functions to draw polygons in Google Maps. However, when you draw the first polygon, and then select the button to draw the second polygon, BOTH of them get drawn. They start to overlap. See my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ECssN/1

The following is what I am using to draw the polygon (from Google Maps API documentation):

```
function polygon1() {
    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: "#F390F9",
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    };
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPolygon1);
}

function addPolygon1(event) {
    var path = poly.getPath();
    path.push(event.latLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    });
}
```

How do I *deselect* the first polygon when the user clicks on the button to draw the second polygon, and vice-versa?

Is jQuery `.unbind` or `.removeAttr` a good way to do this? Not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I clicked the Polygon buttons in JSFiddle, no polygons were drawn. I'm on Chrome btw.

Comment: @Lindsay I am using Chrome as well, and they seem to be working fine at my end. Hmm, not sure. I don't think I have any errors in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save handle to event listener (for first polygon button) and then clear it when you start to draw the second polygon. See [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antojurkovic/ECssN/2/).

```
handle01 = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPolygon1);
...

function polygon2() {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(handle01);
    var polyOptions = {
    ...
```

You can do the same for the second polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to store each polygon into an array, or a single global variable in your case (which you seem to have as `poly`). Check to see if a polygon exists before you set it, and if it does, to unset the map before you set the new one.

```
function polygon1() {
    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: "#F390F9",
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    };
    if( poly )                                        // <-----
        poly.setMap(null);                            // <-----
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPolygon1);
}

function addPolygon1(event) {
    var path = poly.getPath();
    path.push(event.latLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use flags to check if it exists? Also, wouldn't `setMap(null)` remove that polygon from the map?

Comment: It sounds like you want to keep all of the drawn polygon shapes. You can push them all into an array and use `arr[arr.length-1].setMap(null)` to remove them from the map (and DOM) before adding another. But they still are able to be quickly instantiated when you loop through the array and perform `.setMap(map)` again.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. I agree with the chosen answer.